# jTable jquery with struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2, row, addition, jquery-jtable

I'm developing a jquery Jtable with Struts2 , so when I want to add new record or update existing one and I enter new value in the shown popup those values are not recovered by struts action and the new record is added with all null values.
this is my java method:

```
private String nom,identifiant;
private String prenom;
private String email;

// getter/setter...
public String create() throws IOException {
    record = new Student();

    record.setNom(this.getNom());
    record.setPrenom(this.getPrenom());
    record.setEmail(this.getEmail());
    record.setIdentifiant(getIdentifiant());
    try {
        // Create new record

        dao.ajout(record);
        result = "OK";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = "ERROR";
        message = e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return Action.SUCCESS;  
}
```

and here jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Liste des agents pharmaciens',
        paging : true, //Enable paging
       pageSize : 3, //Set page size (default: 10)  
        actions: {
            listAction : 'afficheStudent',
            createAction : 'createAction',
            updateAction : 'updateAction',
            deleteAction : 'deleteAction'
        },
        fields: {
            id: {
                title:'id',
                key: true,
                list: true,

            },
            identifiant: {
                title: 'Identifiant',
                width: '20%',
                edit:true
            },
            nom: {
                title: 'Nom',
                width: '20%',
                edit:true
            },
            prenom: {
                title: 'Prenom',
                width: '30%',
                edit:true,
                create:true
            },
            email: {
                title: 'Email',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true,
                create:true
            }              
        }
    });
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

Comment: Examine what is being sent to server.

Comment: I did , but it seems that values can't be recovered from forms to the actions class in order to be saved in the database

Comment: Open dev tools in your browser, select network tab and see what is being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

One error is that the field nom does not have the create : true option.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Liste des agents pharmaciens',
        paging : true, //Enable paging
       pageSize : 3, //Set page size (default: 10)  
        actions: {
            listAction : 'afficheStudent',
            createAction : 'createAction',
            updateAction : 'updateAction',
            deleteAction : 'deleteAction'
        },
        fields: {
            id: {
                title:'id',
                key: true,
                list: true,

            },
            identifiant: {
                title: 'Identifiant',
                width: '20%',
                edit:true
            },
            nom: {
                title: 'Nom',
                width: '20%',
                edit:true,
                create: true //this is one error
            },
            prenom: {
                title: 'Prenom',
                width: '30%',
                edit:true,
                create:true
            },
            email: {
                title: 'Email',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true,
                create:true
            }              
        }
    });
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

Comment: If this does not completely solve your question I can look it over again

Answer (score 0):

nom field doesn't have create true column.`nom: { title: 'Nom', width: '20%', edit:true, create: true //this is one error },`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).